# Why Starting Android Studio was failed?

Tags: android

When Running Android Studio Girrafe, I didn't know what does it meaning this error:

> Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues
> com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: Key io.flutter.settings.FlutterSettings duplicated; existingAdapter: ServiceAdapter(descriptor=ServiceDescriptor(interface='io.flutter.settings.FlutterSettings', serviceImplementation='io.flutter.settings.FlutterSettings', testServiceImplementation='null', headlessImplementation='null', overrides=false, configurationSchemaKey='null', preload=FALSE, client=null), pluginDescriptor=PluginDescriptor(name=Flutter Storm, id=com.github.beansoftapp.flutter.storm, descriptorPath=plugin.xml, path=~\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2022.3\plugins\flutter-storm, version=2023.1.0, package=null, isBundled=false)); descriptor: io.flutter.settings.FlutterSettings; app: Application  (containerState PRE_INIT) ; current plugin: io.flutterat com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerServices(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:547)at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:259)at com.intellij.openapi.client.ClientAwareComponentManager.registerComponents(ClientAwareComponentManager.kt:46)at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader.doInitApplication(ApplicationLoader.kt:78)at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader.access$doInitApplication(ApplicationLoader.kt:1)at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$doInitApplication$1.invokeSuspend(ApplicationLoader.kt)at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:284)at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85)at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader.initApplication(ApplicationLoader.kt:61)at com.I.I.M.I.Hl.I(Hl.java:60)at com.I.I.M.I.I3.I(I3.java:113)at com.I.I.M.I.IQ.I(IQ.java:139)at com.I.I.M.I.Iw.I(Iw.java:57)at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.kt:13)at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil$startApplication$7.invokeSuspend(StartupUtil.kt:298)at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:284)at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85)at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.kt:36)

---

```
Your JRE: 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231 amd64 (JetBrains s.r.o.)
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr
```

Please Fix this problem

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted? If so, how? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your settings or cache may have become corrupted.

First try renaming

`c:\users\user-id\.Android` to `c:\users\user-id\.AndroidXXX`

If that works, delete the renamed dir. You'll need to recreate emulators.

If that doesn't work, rename it back, then try renaming

`c:\users\user-id\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio*`

and

`c:\users\user-id\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio*`

(If you have multiple versions of Studio installed and this is only happening on one, only rename the `AndroidStudio*` that matches the version that's giving you trouble.)

Put `XXX` at the end of each dir that may be there.

If that works, you've lost your settings but can at least get in. Delete the `XXX` dirs.

Comment: It doesn't work